# $X_n\xrightarrow{P} X$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{P} Y$, then $X_n Y_n\xrightarrow{P}X Y$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How to prove if $X_n\xrightarrow{P} X$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{P} Y$, then $X_n Y_n\xrightarrow{P}X Y$ ?

**Proof Original**
I try to finish it as below.

$P(|X_nY_n-XY|>\epsilon)=P(|X_nY_n-X_nY+X_nY-XY|>\epsilon)=P(|X_n(Y_n-Y)+(X_n-X)Y|>\epsilon)=P(|(X_n-X)(Y_n-Y)+X(Y_n-Y)+(X_n-X)Y|>\epsilon)\leq P(|(X_n-X)(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)+P(|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)+P(|(X_n-X)Y|>\epsilon/3)$

We need to show $P(|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$， that is $Y_n\rightarrow^{P} Y$ and $X$ is a random variable, we want to show $Y_n X\rightarrow^{P} YX$

I use truncate to see this part $P(|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)\leq P(|X|> M, |X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)+P(|X|\geq M, |X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3) \leq P(|X|> M, |X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)+P( |M(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3) \leq P(|(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/(3M))+P( |M(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

The similar to show, $P(|(X_n-X)Y|>\epsilon/3)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

As , we have  $P(|(X_n-X)(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)\leq P(|(X_n-X)|>\epsilon/3)+P(|Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)$ if n is large enough, we can bound $|Y_n-Y|$ and  |X_n-X| by $1$ .  Thus we also have $P(|(X_n-X)(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3) \rightarrow 0$

Thus we prove the inequality.  I only know the definition of convergence in probability. Can any one give some suggestion, either for the proof based on the basic definition or other much simpler proof.

**The proof according to suggestion.**

Since $X_n\xrightarrow{P} X$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{P} Y$

for every subsequence $n_m$, there is a further subsequence $n_{m_k}$, such that $X_{n(m_k)}\xrightarrow{a.s} X$, and

$Y_{n(m_k)}\xrightarrow{a.s} Y$,  thus

$X_{n(m_k)} Y_{n(m_k)}\xrightarrow{a.s} XY$ (still need further proof)

According to the suggestions from my other question. We can show that $\mathbb{P}(X_n Y_n \not\to XY) \leq \mathbb{P}(\{X_n \not\to X\}\cup \{Y_n \not\to Y\}) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_n \not\to X) + \mathbb{P}(Y_n \not\to Y) = 0 + 0 = 0$
Thus $X_{n(m_k)} Y_{n(m_k)}\xrightarrow{a.s} XY$
Thus , for every subsequence $n_m$, there is a further subsequence $n_{m_k}$, such that $X_{n(m_k)}\xrightarrow{a.s} X$,(for the only if part of the theorem statement, we can conclude that),$X_n Y_n\xrightarrow{P} XY$.

(According to the theorem:  $X_n\xrightarrow{P} X$ if and only if for every subsequence $n_m$, there is a further subsequence $n_{m_k}$, such that
$X_{n(m_k)} \xrightarrow{a.s} X$ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple proof can be given using the fact that $X_n \to X$ in probability iff every subsequence of $(X_n)$ has  a further subsequence which converges almost surely. Start with a subsequence of $\{X_nY_n\}$ and find a subsequence which converges almost surely.